# RoR - Values from forms are not getting passed to controller

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a subscriber form page, where based on the country selected I display the state field via jquery. That part works fine but even after selecting a state when I post, I get an error "state value can't be blank". Not sure what I am missing. 
Here is the code.

```
    <% if session[:selcountry] == "USA" %>
    <div id="usstates">
    <div class="form-group">
    <%= label_tag :state %><span class="asterisk"> *</span><br>
    <%= select_tag :state, options_for_select(us_states), class: "form-
    control" %>
    </div>
    </div>
    <% else %>
    <div id="canstates" style="display:none;">
    <div class="form-group">
    <%= label_tag :province %><span class="asterisk"> *</span><br>
    <%= select_tag :state, options_for_select(can_states), class: "form-
    control" %>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div id="intlstates">
    <div class="form-group">
    <%= label_tag :state %><span class="asterisk"> *</span><br>
    <%= text_field_tag :state, @subscriber.state, class: "form-control" %>
    </div>
    </div>
    <% end %>
```

Any pointers would be great.
TIA

Comment: You will need to add the code.

Comment: You have to give some example or some code you tried .

Comment: Udated the post with the code

Comment: Can you post your controller, specifically where you whitelist params?